# In c binary, testing to see if a number is in range

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, puzzle

This is part of a puzzle that I can't figure out. The function takes in three inputs. The first is an int, the second is the lower bound and the third is the upper bound. I need to test to see if that first number is within the lower and upper bound inclusive.

If it is in range then return 1, else return 0. 
The catch is that I can only use

```
! ~ & ^ | + << >>
```

operations and only a combination of 20 of them.. Also, only int variables may be used, and no if statements, loops or function calls.

```
Range(int x, int lower, int upper){
//... some code here
return retVal;
}
```

Obviously I understand the logic here. If((x >= lower) && (x <= upper)) return 1;
The only problem is that I can't use if statements, <, >, ==, or &&.

Comment: What have you attempted?  Regardless of code, Do you have any ideas or concepts of how such a process might work?

Comment: I'm thinking knowledge of 2's complement representation would be a good place to start.

Comment: I'll try and get back the code I worked on. I did the stupid thing and deleted my code and started from scratch in frustration haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm liking these puzzles you have! For this you will want to have something like,

Ok to be abstract on this one, you will want to have 2 variables.

The first variable (lets call it blarg) you need to set the upper bound and add the flipped x.
Now you will want to add one to blarg and flip it.

Your second variable (lets call it hold) will add the x to the flipped lower bound; After that add 1 to hold and flip it too.

set blarg = to the blarg plus hold;
shift blarg over 31 to the the right.
and AND it with 1.

Should be what you are looking for.

Comment: It actually lowers the number of ops being used! Thanks

Comment: Aren't you also just rewriting subtractions into adding and flipping? That can't work. Consider negative bounds (that already have their top bit set), and consider highly-negative bounds and a positive value that makes the subtraction (no matter how you rewrite it) overflow.

Answer (score 8):

You can make the comparison predicate `x < y` (returning -1 if true, 0 if false) like this: (see Hacker's Delight, Chapter 2, sub-chapter Comparison Predicates)

```
((x - y) ^ ((x ^ y) & ((x - y) ^ x))) >> 31;
```

You didn't list subtraction, but you can emulate `x - y` with `~(~x + y)`

Using two of these predicates, make `1 & ~((x < lower) | (upper < x))`

This obviously assumes 2's complement negatives and 32 bit integers with wrapping on overflow. So this is not portable, but that's the norm with this kind of trick.

---

As requested, that makes the total thing:

```
int in_range(int x, int lower, int upper)
{
    int p = ((x - lower) ^ ((x ^ lower) & ((x - lower) ^ x))) >> 31;
    int q = ((upper - x) ^ ((upper ^ x) & ((upper - x) ^ upper))) >> 31;
    return 1 & ~(p | q);
}
```

It still has the subtractions, they're trivial to replace if you really want.

It's possible to make it a tiny tiny bit shorter by using the `>=` and `<=` predicates (which can also be found in Hacker's Delight).

Here's my website saying it's [correct](http://goo.gl/RGN4RX).

---

And here's a way that uses less operations, keeping in mind we can't use subtraction:

```
int p = (x | ~upper) & ((x ^ upper) | (~upper + x));
int q = (lower | ~x) & ((lower ^ x) | (~x + lower));
return 1 & ((p & q) >> 31);
```

It uses the `<=` predicate from HD, which looks like `(x | ~y) & ((x ^ y) | ~(y - x))` in its pure form.

And here's my website saying it's [correct](http://goo.gl/vr6sAq).

Answer (score 3):

do this. i'll tell the logic that can be used.

```
a=~x+1    //gives -x
b=lower+a   //lower-x
c=~upper+1    //gives -upper
d=x+c           //x-upper  
b=b&0x80000000;   //get the msb which is 1 if -ve number
d=d&0x80000000;
return ((b&d)|(!(x^lower))|(!(x^upper)));  //& results in +ve only if both b & d are +ve
```

Comment: Since all you've done is rewrite a subtraction into something else, this can not possibly be correct. Consider what would happen if the bounds are negative, for example.

Comment: @harold it worked for both +ve, +ve & -ve and both -ve bounds. all cases. i checked it again. it works. if you still think it doesnt. give me one input combination for that this logic may go wrong. i would like to trace and check for correctness.

Comment: Ok, how about `lower = -1, upper = -1, x = -1`? That would give 0, it should give 1 (of course your code never gives 1, so I assumed you had to shift it right by 31)

Comment: @harold ya it dint work when lower bound or upper bound equals the value. now i changed the statement. now it does work for all value. thankyou

Comment: Good yes I see I mistake when calculating that, so let's try `lower = 0x800000000, upper = -1, x = 0x7fffffff`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a humble solution

```
int foo(int num, int upp, int low){
        return (~((~(upp + ~num + 1)) ^ (~(num + ~low + 1))) >> 31) & 1;
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll fix that

Comment: That's cool and all, but it doesn't work. More accurately, it works *only sometimes*, and those cases in which it works are more obvious than those in which it does not. However, try `low = -1, upp = -1, num = -1`. Since that bounds are inclusive, you should get 1. But you get 0.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, it should have worked for +ve numbers only, I fixed that by replacing the AND by XNOR and I think it works now for both +ve and -ve numbers, Plz check it and tell me if there is something wrong.

Comment: Now it doesn't work for (for example) `low = -1, upp = -1, num = 0x7fffffff`

Comment: @harold No, I think it works well, it outputs ZERO and this is right since 0x7fffffff is a +ve number and then it is out of range.

Comment: Ok yes, I've made a mistake, `low` should have been -2